# How can use a detail view for editing a observed object and use for add a new value

Tags: swiftui, core-data

in the moment I have two views for editing and for add a new item. How can I open the view for editing the item with nil to the observed object and then use for add a new item?

I would open the detailview with this code, but the try to open with the Button "open edit as new" with selectedTool as nil would not work.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(tools) { tool in
                NavigationLink {
                    ToolsEditView(selectedTool: tool)
                } label: {
                    Text("\(tool.wrappedName) | \(Int(tool.ankle))°")
                }
            }
            .onDelete(perform: deleteItem)
        }
        .navigationTitle("grindingtools")
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: addButton)
        
        Button(action:  {
            ToolsEditView(selectedTool: nil?)
        }, label: {
            Text("open edit as new")
        })

    }
}
```

In the detailview I have in the moment only the saveChanges for the selected item. And in the .onAppear, I get the selected data. But I feel in the moment, that I be on the point, where I need a little tip in which way I have to look

```
struct ToolsEditView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    @ObservedObject var selectedTool: ToolsEntity
    
    @State private var toolname: String = ""
    @State private var winkel: Double = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            VStack {
                TextField("add toolname", text: $toolname)
                    .textFieldStyle(TextTextFieldStyle(icon: Image(systemName: "pencil")))
            }
            
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("grindankle")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .frame(width: 100)
                        .onAppear { self.toolname = self.selectedTool.wrappedName }
                    
                    Slider(value: $winkel , in: 0.0...32.0, step: 1.0)
                        .onAppear { self.winkel = self.selectedTool.ankle }
                    Text(
                        String(format: "%.0f °", winkel)
                    )
                }
            }
            
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Button("chancel") {
                        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(ChancelButton())
                    
                    Button("save") {
                        saveChanges()
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(AddButton())
                }
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            hideKeyboard()
        }
    }
    
    private func saveChanges() {
        selectedTool.name = toolname
        selectedTool.ankle = winkel
        try? selectedTool.managedObjectContext?.save()
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a custom initializer for your view. The way you have it set up means that the view expects a fully fledged Core Data entity and you are trying to pass `nil`. In order to do what you are attempting, your view would have to look like this:

```
struct ToolsEditView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    // For the sake of the answer, I am assuming you injected the 
    // ManagedObjectContext into the environment.
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context

    @ObservedObject var selectedTool: ToolsEntity
    
    @State private var toolname: String = ""
    @State private var winkel: Double = 0
    
    // selectedTool in the init is allowed to be an optional, even though
    // self.selectedTool is non-optional. We handle that below.
    init(selectedTool: ToolsEntity?) {
        // We try to unwrap selectedTool
        if let selectedTool {
            // We succeeded in unwrapping selectedTool, so we can assign it.
            self.selectedTool = selectedTool
        } else {
            // selectedTool was nil, so we have to create our own
            let newTool = ToolsEntity(context: context)
            newTool.name = ...
            newTool.ankle = ...

            self.selectedTool = newTool
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        ...
    }
}
```

Once you get comfortable handling this pattern reliably, look into child contexts.

Comment: Now I got the error:  Variable 'self.selectedTool' used before being initialized

Mhm, have I initialize it also in the init?

Comment: Add your updated code of just `ToolsEditView` to the bottom of your question and we will see what you did wrong. Also post a pic of the error from Xcode so we can see where it is.